# DYLD, no cache image with name (@rpath/libswiftCore.dylib)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, tvos

I'm getting a crash on tvOS 12.2 with the following details:

```
Incident Identifier: 57DC9DA3-536C-438E-91A0-2A3BF5290302
CrashReporter Key:   336395bb8937c2da230441e7d0f77cf6ce5d29e2
Hardware Model:      AppleTV5,3
Process:             yospace-tvos-test [535]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/8D86BE15-0069-48A0-A6CC-AF32ABCB718B/yospace-tvos-test.app/yospace-tvos-test
Identifier:          com.x..yospace-tvos-test
Version:             1 (1.0)
AppStoreTools:       11C504
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.x..yospace-tvos-test [856]


Date/Time:           2020-02-06 09:25:36.5008 +0000
Launch Time:         2020-02-06 09:25:36.2246 +0000
OS Version:          Apple TVOS 12.2 (16L5201d)
Baseband Version:    n/a
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Description: DYLD, no cache image with name (@rpath/libswiftCore.dylib)
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   dyld                            0x00000001009b63b8 __abort_with_payload + 8
1   dyld                            0x00000001009b59f8 abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal + 100
2   dyld                            0x00000001009b5a28 fcntl + 0
3   dyld                            0x00000001009788fc dyld::fastBindLazySymbol+ 18684 (ImageLoader**, unsigned long) + 0
4   dyld                            0x000000010097b6e8 dyld::_main+ 30440 (macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*) + 5396
5   dyld                            0x0000000100975044 _dyld_start + 68

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000006   x1: 0x0000000000000009   x2: 0x000000016f56a980   x3: 0x0000000000000014
    x4: 0x000000016f56a580   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000420
    x8: 0x0000000000000020   x9: 0x0000000000000009  x10: 0x0000000000000001  x11: 0x0000000100a34000
   x12: 0x0000000100a34000  x13: 0x0000000000000007  x14: 0x6172462f7070612e  x15: 0x00736b726f77656d
   x16: 0x0000000000000209  x17: 0x0000000000000010  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000000
   x20: 0x000000016f56a580  x21: 0x0000000000000014  x22: 0x000000016f56a980  x23: 0x0000000000000009
   x24: 0x0000000000000006  x25: 0x000000000000002f  x26: 0x00000001009cf5e0  x27: 0x00000001009cf000
   x28: 0x00000001009cfa00   fp: 0x000000016f56a550   lr: 0x00000001009b59f8
    sp: 0x000000016f56a510   pc: 0x00000001009b63b8 cpsr: 0x40000000

EOF
```

If I run the app through Xcode it's fine but when I export it as an IPA and install it on the Apple TV it crashes instantly during launch. It works fine from IPA on tvOS 13 and iOS 11-13. I'm guessing it's something to do with the Swift ABI stability in tvOS 13 so it doesn't need the Swift libs for 13, but does for 12 and even though I've said it should always embed the swift standard libs it's struggling to find them, or indeed include them at all based on the lack of Swift libs in the binary images listed at the end of the crash log (not included above due to body length limits).

The console for the Apple TV reports the following:

> Attempt to add an app with insufficient id, info {
>       BKSApplicationStateAppIsFrontmost = 1;
>       BKSApplicationStateExtensionKey = 0;
>       SBApplicationStateDisplayIDKey = "com.x..yospace-tvos-test";
>       SBApplicationStateKey = 8;
>       SBApplicationStateProcessIDKey = 535;
>       SBMostElevatedStateForProcessID = 8; }

It may (or may not) be relevant that the app is written in ObjC and is using a Swift framework.

I've seen a lot of posts about libswiftCore not being loaded but that happens when connected with Xcode rather than when installing from an IPA. I've not had any luck finding anyone with this crash message, nor any luck with the 'Attempt to add an app with insufficient id' message (though people seem to have hit that more often).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround for this issue. Simply adding a dummy Swift file (with a dummy class in it) to the ObjC app project resolved the issue. No need to have a bridging header, nor any need to actually reference the dummy class anywhere.

It doesn't answer the question of why it's happened, but perhaps there's an issue in Xcode and this just forces it to include the Swift standard libraries.